# What website should i use to master german?

Tags: standard-german

I need to learn german but I don't know where to start.
thanks,

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/21i0y4/here_are_about_18_gbs_of_resources_for_learning/

Comment: Writing "I" as capital letter, "you" instead of "u", these are all must-have to master English. German is similar, although most of its users are literate.